# Magento2: How to create a page same as Product view page?

Tags: magento2, product, module, extensions, view

In my custom extension, I want to display product view page same to same in Popup. Can anyone help me how to display product view page or create a page same as product view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a page same as product view page is not easy. It required lot of customization. I will recommend to use Quickveiw extension.